# CSV download from Github link gives tokenizing error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, url, data-science

When trying to import this CSV from Github I get an error:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://github.com/authman/DAT210x/blob/master/Module2/Datasets/tutorial.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Gives the following exception:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 114, saw 3
```

Answer (score 3):

That url is an HTML webpage, you need the "raw" link:

```
In [11]: url = "https://github.com/authman/DAT210x/raw/master/Module2/Datasets/tutorial.csv"

In [12]: pd.read_csv(url)
Out[12]:
       col0      col1      col2      col3
0 -0.722876 -1.330682  1.309208  0.232378
1  1.160396 -0.730879  0.677368  1.044722
2 -1.062870 -0.503704 -0.238536 -1.417937
3  0.437078  0.362640 -0.111228 -1.649853
```